# How to a jar file include another jar via Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I have 'test.jar' . I want to create 'my.jar' . I want my.jar include test.jar

My code:

```
<target name="jar" >
  <copy file="${conf.dir}/default.xml" todir="${build.classes}" />
  <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/test.jar" basedir="${build.classes}">
   <manifest>
   </manifest>
  </jar>
 </target>

 <target name="services-jar">
    <jar jarfile="${build.dir}/my.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="mypackage.MyClass" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${build.dir}/test.jar" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

If I run 'my.jar' : `java -jar my.jar`
display message:  `Could not find or load main class mypackage.MyClass`

My *MANIFEST.MF* file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_17-b02 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: mypackage.MyClass
Class-Path: ./build/test.jar
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths in the manifest `Class-Path` need to be relative to the location of the JAR file that contains the manifest.  Since both `my.jar` and `test.jar` are in the same directory (`${build.dir}`) the relative path is simply `test.jar`, i.e. you need

```
<jar jarfile="${build.dir}/my.jar">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="mypackage.MyClass" />
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="test.jar" />
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

More generally, you may wish to look up the `<manifestclasspath>` task which, given the location of the target JAR file and a set of other JARs that you want to put on the `Class-Path`, calculates all the relative paths for you and generates the correct value for the manifest attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing separators. Replace your`"${build.dir}\test.jar"` with `"${build.dir}/test.jar"`.